# Retrieve data between yesterday at 0700 and today at 0700

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I am trying to come up with a SQL query that retrieves data starting from 0700 yesterday to 0700 today. I tried below, but I am not getting the correct values.

```
where datediff(hour, Incident_Call_Date_Time,getutcdate()) between 6 and 30
```

the data in the field is in the following format:

```
2020-10-28 22:16:30.000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
WHERE Incident_Call_Date_Time >= CONVERT(DATETIME, FORMAT(DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()), 'yyyy-MM-dd') + ' 07:00')
AND Incident_Call_Date_Time < CONVERT(DATETIME, FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'yyyy-MM-dd') + ' 07:00')
```

It gets yesterday and today's date as string (no time part), adds 07:00 to the dates as the new time part, and checks to see if your value is between those to new DATETIME values.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
where Incident_Call_Date_Time
    between dateadd(hh, 7, cast(cast(getutcdate() - 1 as date) as datetime))
        and dateadd(hh, 7, cast(cast(getutcdate()     as date) as datetime))
```